# Writing to a CSV File from Array

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I am trying to use `writer.writerow` to present data from an array to an csv file. I have an array `sum_balance` and apparently I need to convert it into a numpy array before I can use the `writer.writerow` function. Heres my code:

```
numpy_arr = array(sum_balance)
with open("output.csv", "wb") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for element in numpy_arr:
        writer.writerow(element)
csv_file.close()
```

But I still get the error: `writer.writerow(element)_csv.Error: iterable expected, not numpy.float64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `numpy` iterator seems to be iterating over elements, not rows, which is why you're getting an error.  However, there's an even simpler way to achieve what you're trying to do:  `numpy` has a routine [`savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt) that can write an `ndarray` to a csv file:

```
output_array = np.array(my_data)
np.savetxt("my_output_file.csv", output_array, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: It prints it row by row, is it possible to print it column by column?

Comment: Yes.  Any `numpy.ndarray` can be transposed with `array_name.T`.  So to write with columns as rows you just need to do `np.savetext("output_file_name", array_name.T, delimiter=',')`.